# In R, It doesn't take data in hindi, if i assign a data frame

Tags: r

In R, it doesn't take data written in hindi, if a data frame is assigned. 
My code is:

```
translate(content.vec = newdata$French, 
          google.api.key = "API key 1kd", 
          source.lang = 'hi', target.lang = 'en')
```

Error is:

> Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Also, data which is in hindi. It turned like this

```
X..U.092A..U.094D..U.0930..U.092F..U.094B..U.0917..
```

in R.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]! Please show the code you are using! Is there any error or what other is wrong?

Comment: Please put the new information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51892561/edit In my installation of `R` there is no function `translate()`

Comment: There's a package translateR

Comment: Again, please put the new information about used additional packages in your question (not in a comment), i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51892561/edit How can one reproduce the issue? read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example